# WordPress Multisite Subsite WP admin not working

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping

I used the MU Domain Mapping plugin to map the domains, Currently, I am not able to login into other subsites which are pointed to other domains.

It is showing me the error.

**The domain mapping plugin only works if the site is installed in /. This is a limitation of how virtual servers work and is very difficult to work around.**

I used the below settings in wp-config file.

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'mydomainname');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

define( 'SUNRISE', 'on' ); 

define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '');
//define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
```

Please help me.

Answer (score -1):

This is because your admin user account isn't recognised on sub-domains anymore.  Log into the network dashboard sites section, `http://<your-domain>/wp-admin/network/sites.php`, edit each of your sub-domains and add your user account as an admin role.

Comment: you may also have to clear your cache/reset the wordpress [salts](https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/).